# Is there a formula to have a cell display contents of a cell on another tab depending on an input on the current tab?

Tags: excel

I am building a text generator and would like to simplify things as much as possible. I have a 2 column table on one tab that lists over 100 medications along with their drug codes (ex: A1 = Aspirin, A2 = 62211-0220).

Is there a formula that I could include in my text generator or somewhere on the tab that would look at the drug code that was input in one cell, and reference the corresponding drug name from the table on the separate tab?

This is for MS excel. I have tried using nested if statements, however there are too many medications for a single formula.

Heres an example of how its set up.
Program scrapes our data and grabs the following data points:
(A1) drug code
(A2) unit of measure
(A3) date dispensed. 
(A4) patient
(A5) amount dispensed

My formula currently looks like this:
="On "&TEXT(A3,"mm/dd/yyyy")&" "&A4&" received "&A5&" "&A2&" of "&A1&"."

The above formula reads out like this:
On 01/01/2019 John Doe received 325 mg of 69618-010.

I would like the drug code to instead display the corresponding drug name from the separate tab.

So basically, I would like to know how to have excel automatically display the medication name in a cell from another tab depending on the drug code present from the data scrape. I can then just reference this cell in my text generating formula. Hope this makes sense....

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `VLOOKUP` and/or `INDEX/MATCH`

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! If anyone else runs into this, I used an Index/match function.